Income from a Fake Certificate
Aoa, I am Muneeb Ahmed and I did a course in mobile app development from an organization which required 16 years of education which I did not have at that time. I learnt everything which they taught. Now I came to know it comes under fake certificate and its income is haram. Now if I relearn that skill from another source like youtube or udemy, will its income be considered halal? If the contents of course from the fake certificate and new course are exactly the same
Thank you in advance
